# Why are images very low quality when exporting with fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am working on an application where I will need to export the canvas as an SVG at the end.

When I add an image to the canvas, it shows with the expected quality, but when I export the canvas the image is completely blurred out.

How can I prevent this?

I have been playing with the setHeight/Width and scaleToHeight/Width, as well as with object caching and it doesn't seem to make any difference.

How I am creating my canvas:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
        imageSmoothingEnabled: false
    });
```

How I am adding the image to the canvas:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('hall1.svg', function (myImg) {
        let img1 = myImg.set({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            scaleX: 2,
            scaleY: 2
        });
        canvas.add(img1);
    });
```

How I am exporting the canvas:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/path/to/project/svg.php',
    data: {
       preview: true,
       previewData: canvas.toSVG({ suppressPreamble: true })
    }
})
```

```
 file_put_contents("../../preview.svg", $_POST['previewData']);
 echo 'preview.svg';
```

[Expected quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR5W7.png)

[Actual quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzuMx.png)